# Flutter localization - Text was called on Null

Tags: flutter, localization

I am trying to implement the localization for my Flutter app. But there is an error which is `The method 'text' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: text("title")`.

The problem comes from the language selector page where upon selecting the language. The title should have changed according to the language. Currently there are English and Chinese language.

```
import 'package:MyApp/services/AppTranslations.dart';
import 'package:MyApp/services/Application.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class LanguageSelectorPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LanguageSelectorPageState createState() => _LanguageSelectorPageState();
}

class _LanguageSelectorPageState extends State<LanguageSelectorPage> {
  //languagesList also moved to the Application class just like the languageCodesList
  static final List<String> languagesList = application.supportedLanguages;
  static final List<String> languageCodesList =
      application.supportedLanguagesCodes;

  final Map<dynamic, dynamic> languagesMap = {
    languagesList[0]: languageCodesList[0],
    languagesList[1]: languageCodesList[1],
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          AppTranslations.of(context).text("title") //This is where the error come from
        ),
      ),
      body: _buildLanguagesList(),
    );
  }

  _buildLanguagesList() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: languagesList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return _buildLanguageItem(languagesList[index]);
      },
    );
  }

  _buildLanguageItem(String language) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        print(language);
        application.onLocaleChanged(Locale(languagesMap[language]));
      },
      child: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
          child: Text(
            language,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 24.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Inside my json file there is title.

```
{
    "title" : "Testing Title",
}
```

This is my AppTranslations

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

class AppTranslations {
  Locale locale;
  static Map<dynamic, dynamic> _localisedValues;

  AppTranslations(Locale locale) {
    this.locale = locale;
    _localisedValues = null;
  }

  static AppTranslations of(BuildContext context) {
    return Localizations.of<AppTranslations>(context, AppTranslations);
  }

  static Future<AppTranslations> load(Locale locale) async {
    AppTranslations appTranslations = AppTranslations(locale);
    String jsonContent = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/lang/${locale.languageCode}.json");
    _localisedValues = json.decode(jsonContent);
    return appTranslations;
  }

  get currentLanguage => locale.languageCode;

  String text(String key) {
    return _localisedValues[key] ?? "$key not found";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have followed below video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lDfbbTvq4qM&t=611s

then you will definitely be going to get a null error.

This is how I fixed the issue.

**JUST CHANGE :**
**From this**

```
localeResolutionCallback: (locale, supportedLocales) {
        // Check if the current device locale is supported
        for (var supportedLocale in supportedLocales) {
          if (supportedLocale.languageCode == locale.languageCode &&
              supportedLocale.countryCode == locale.countryCode) {
            return supportedLocale;
          }
        }
        // If the locale of the device is not supported, use the first one
        // from the list (English, in this case).
        return supportedLocales.first;
      },
```

**To this**

```
localeResolutionCallback: (locale, supportedLocales) {
        // Check if the current device locale is supported
        for (var supportedLocale in supportedLocales) {
          if (supportedLocale.languageCode == locale?.languageCode ||
              supportedLocale.countryCode == locale?.countryCode) {
            return supportedLocale;
          }
        }
        // If the locale of the device is not supported, use the first one
        // from the list (English, in this case).
        return supportedLocales.first;
      },
```

It will work..!